# How to resolve /dev/disk/by-* to device in a shell script?

Tags: scripting, partition, symlink, block-device

In a (Bash) shell script I do wish to resolve a partition label — f.e. `/dev/disk/by-label/X` — to the corresponding device (partition)number: `/dev/sdX1`.

How can I resolve a `/dev/disk/by` to `/dev/sdX`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `readlink -f`

Where -f is --canonicalize:

> canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the
>   given name recursively; all but the last component must exist

*Example:*

```
$ readlink -f /dev/disk/by-label/my_partition_label
/dev/sdb1
```